# An interesting number theory question for math contest training $x^2+x=2y^3$ (finding integer solutions)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

This question is in one of my old notebook and I marked it as a solved problem. However, somehow I can't remember the proof or maybe my solution in the past was wrong. The first thing I tried is to muptiply both sides by 4 and then plus to get the equation to the form: $(2x+1)^2=(2y+1)(4y^2-2y+1)$. There are 2 cases, if $2y+1$ and $4y^2-2y+1$ are coprime then the rest is easy. However, if $gcd(2y+1,4y^2-2y+1)=3$, I have tried multiple ways and failed to finish the proof.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this: $x(x+1)=2y^3$ and $gcd(x,x+1)=1$. This implies $x=a^3,x+1=2b^3$ or $x=2a^3,x+1=b^3$. Try solving $2b^3=a^3+1$ or $b^3=2a^3+1$ now...

Comment: Extra hint: cubes get really far apart so you only need to consider small “obvious” solutions.

Comment: I have tried this approach but I still have trouble  when the greatest common divisor of the factors is 3. Maybe you do not factorize $a^3+1$ and $b^3-1$ here? How did you proceed?

Comment: No it’s much simpler actually. You see the equation $x^3+y^3=2z^3$ has only the obvious solutions $x=y=z$ and $x=-y,z=0$ so you have either $y=1$ or $y=-1$ in your case and it is easy to find the rest.

Comment: I see. So you mean $a^3-b^3=b^3-1$ or $b^3-a^3=a^3-(-1)^3$ and consider the difference between  the cubes. That must have been the old solution I forgot!. Thanks so much. Guess my brain lacks practice recently.

Comment: $\pm 2x^3+x^2+1=2(y^3\pm x^2) \Rightarrow x(\pm 2x^2+x+1)=2(y\pm x)(y^2\pm x y + x^2)$

Comment: Yes exactly! You can use the trivial solutions afterwards to substitute. You might also want to consider viewing this as an elliptic curve which makes the problem quite easy to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by $4$ to get: $$(2x+1)^2-1=(2y)^3$$
It is known since Euler that [this equation](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=cmFtYW51amFubWF0aHNvY2lldHkub3JnfHJtc3xneDo2NTcyMmZhOTBiYWJhZjY2)(check page 6)  implies $2y=0, 2, -1$. Therefore, $y=0$ and $x=-1$ or $y=1$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome. You can simply solve this equation:

$x^2+x-2y^3=0$

$\Delta=1+8y^3$

$y=1$  ⇒ $\Delta=9$ ⇒ $x=1$ and $x=-2$

I think these are only integer solutions. you can work on $\Delta$ for various values of y.

Comment: Just a minor correction: you get $\Delta^2=1+(2y)^3$ which is really Euler's equation and only has three integer solutions. I highly doubt this answer is what OP is looking for considering it uses results on elliptic curves for the proof which can provide an immediate answer anyway.